# I am trying to program the rate of a disease in different ages, and I need to write it as a percentage which has a precision of two decimal points

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n,less18=0,nineteento35=0,thirty6to60=0,greater60=0;
    double rate1,rate2,rate3,rate4;
    cin>> n;
    int i,year[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>year[i];
    }//input all the data
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(year[i]<=18){
            less18++;
        }

        if (year[i]>=19&&year[i]<=35){
            nineteento35++;
        }
        if (year[i]>=36&&year[i]<=60){
            thirty6to60++;
        }
        if (year[i]>60){
            greater60++;
        }}
        rate1=less18*100/n;
        rate2=nineteento35*100/n;
        rate3=thirty6to60*100/n;
        rate4=greater60*100/n;

        cout<<"1-18: "<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<rate1<<"%"<<'\n';

        cout<<"19-35: "<<rate2<<"%"<<'\n';
        cout<<"36-60: "<<rate3<<"%"<<'\n';
        cout<<"60-: "  <<rate4<<"%"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it it always shows me integral percentage such as 20% or 33%.  How can I make it have two decimal points? 
After I used another IDE and it showed me numbers such as 33.00% but it is supposed to show 33.33%. how can I make it do that? Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

In your calculations of the rates, i.e.:

```
rate1=less18*100/n;
rate2=nineteento35*100/n;
rate3=thirty6to60*100/n;
rate4=greater60*100/n;
```

All the things on the right hand side of the `=` are integers, so it does integer multiplication and integer division, which results in an integer. If you make one of the numbers a double, i.e:

```
rate1=less18*100.0/n;
rate2=nineteento35*100.0/n;
rate3=thirty6to60*100.0/n;
rate4=greater60*100.0/n;
```

. Where 100.0 is a double, compared to 100 which is an integer. It will convert the other variables to doubles and then do what you expect.